# Twitter API 401's on /account/verify_credentials

Tags: android, kotlin, twitter, oauth

I am trying to make use of the twitter api, and am setting up a handler to deal with twitter api requests.

To do this I am using an `HTTPUrlConnection` and following the Twitter api docs

I've managed to get authenticated using the 3-legged OAuth process, but am stuck when actually trying to make requests with the oauth token.

Here is an example of what my auth headers look like:

```
Accept=*/*, 
Connection=close, 
User-Agent=OAuth gem v0.4.4, 
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, 
Authorization=
OAuth oauth_consumer_key=****&
oauth_nonce=bbmthpoiuq&
oauth_signature=*****%3D&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp=1570586135&
oauth_token=*****&
oauth_version=1.0,
Host=api.twitter.com
```

for each header in the auth header I add it to my HTTP `GET` call like this:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty(header.key, header.value)
```

Note that `Authorization` points to one string

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key=****&oauth_nonce=bbmthpoiuq&oauth_signature=*****%3Doauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1oauth_timestamp=1570586135&oauth_token=*****&oauth_version=1.0,Host=api.twitter.com
```

The following params are collected as follows:

- `oauth_consumer_key` is my application API key
- `oauth_signature` is computed by the `hmacSign` function below
- `oauth_token` is the "oauth_token" received in the response from `/oauth/access_token`

The `hmacSign` function:

```
    private fun hmacSign(requestType: RequestType, url: String, params: Map<String, String>): String {
        val type = "HmacSHA1"
        val key = "$API_SECRET&$tokenSecret"
        val value = makeURLSafe("${requestType.string}&$url${getURLString(params.toList().sortedBy { it.first }.toMap())}")

        val mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(type)
        val secret = javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), type)
        mac.init(secret)
        val digest = mac.doFinal(value.toByteArray())

        return makeURLSafe(Base64.encodeToString(digest, NO_WRAP))
    }

    private fun makeURLSafe(url: String) : String {
        return url.replace("/", "%2F")
            .replace(",", "%2C")
            .replace("=", "%3D")
            .replace(":", "%3A")
            .replace(" ", "%2520")
    }

    protected fun getURLString(params: Map<String, Any>) : String {
        if (params.isEmpty()) return ""

        return params.toList().fold("?") { total, current ->
            var updated = total

            updated += if (total == "?")
                "${current.first}=${current.second}"
            else
                "&${current.first}=${current.second}"

            updated
        }
    }
```

In the `GET` call I'm referring to, `tokenSecret` would be the oauth secret received from `/oauth/access_token`

After i make the call I get a `400: Bad Request`

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

---

Update: By putting the params at the end of the url like `?key=value&key2=value2...` instead of a 400 I get a 401. So I'm not sure which is worse, or which is the right way to do it.

Comment: One trick to help determine what the headers should look like is using either Twurl or Postman and inspect the request. You should also follow [these instructions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request). Is this missing the nonce and are you also encoding the url params?

Comment: @osowskit those are the instructions i followed to get the header i have - not sure what twurl or postman is but i can look into them and see if it will help

Comment: @osowskit I also do have a nonce, but i guess i had it commented out when i got the logs for this question will update that now

Comment: @osowskit Okay, so i just downloaded postman, and copied all the auth info i have (my api key/secret and the token secret i get from oauth response) I set the nonce and signature meathod - and then when i choose `Add authorization data to - Request Headers`, it works!

Comment: @osowskit so whats the correct way to mimic this postman request in android?

Comment: @osowskit never mind, managed to figure it out by mimicing the postman header - will add an answer soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, finally got it working

So using the suggestion in the comments, I downloaded postman and copied all my info into postman - when i made the request there, I got a 200!

So then i looked back and tried to figure out what was different and there were a few things:

First the hmac sign function was missing an `&`

New function (added another `&` after the url):

```
    private fun hmacSign(requestType: RequestType, url: String, params: Map<String, String>): String {
        val type = "HmacSHA1"
        val key = "$API_SECRET&$tokenSecret"
        val value = makeURLSafe("${requestType.string}&$url&${getURLString(params.toList().sortedBy { it.first }.toMap())}")

        val mac = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(type)
        val secret = javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), type)
        mac.init(secret)
        val digest = mac.doFinal(value.toByteArray())

        return makeURLSafe(Base64.encodeToString(digest, NO_WRAP))
    }
```

Next I noticed my auth header had its params seperated with `&` but they all should've been replaced with `,` - i also needed to surround each of my values in `""`

So it looked like:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="****",oauth_nonce="bbmthpoiuq",oauth_signature="*****%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1570586135",oauth_token="*****",oauth_version="1.0",Host="api.twitter.com"
```

After these changes i started getting 200!

Hopefully this helps someone else (though im sure its unlikely considering how specific these issues were)